# Client API security in REST services

Tags: security, rest, jersey, client-side, basic-authentication

Firstly, let me say that I'm a noob regarding REST services, and Client APIs...

I'm developing some REST web services using Jersey and Glassfish 3.1.2, in NetBeans. Those REST services already exist, and they were all automatically generated from a MySQL DataBase.

My next step is the security! 
I already implemented **Basic-Authentication** on my REST services, and is all working (a window with login/password appears in the web when I enter in the REST services mainpage). The login and password are in my DataBase.

Now I want to implement security when a **client API** tries to consume the REST services. What is the easy and best way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: (1) What kind of clients do you use? Other servers? Heavy-clients? Ajax? (2) Do you have different credentials for every end-user? One per client? One key pair for all?

Comment: @Aurélien The main point is to develop a java application to consume those services. The credentials of each user are in my DataBase, in a Login table. All the clients that are registered in the DataBase can consume the REST services.

Comment: I'm reading about **HTTPBasicAuthFilter**, do you think it is a solution?

Comment: You should be aware that even if you use the vanilla `java.net.HttpURLConnection`, Java will show a default login window to the user (on 403 status). Your jar must be signed though.

Comment: @Aurélien is that an alternative to jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter?

Comment: I have no experience with Jersey. But, alternatively, you can connect any REST service with the default java HTTP client library. And it's interesting to know that you need zero code to ask the user for her login and password.

Answer (score 0):

The entry point for your REST service needs to be where the security is implemented if it's publicly accessible.  You can't rely on the fact that users are *supposed* to go through the login screen to get access to the service.

That means that the entry point of the service needs to perform sufficient validation to know that the request is legitimate.  This can be accomplished by sending the client's credentials directly to the service, *regardless* of the request.

For example, in some REST services I've seen, it might look something like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces("application/xml")
public String theService(@FormParam("someData") String someData, @FormParam("clientProfile") String clientProfile) {
    //parse XML into ClientProfile
    //attempt to authenticate ClientProfile
    //if authentication is unsuccessful, return error message
    //else, perform service's function
}
```

Of course, don't take this model directly and send things like usernames and passwords in plain-text XML over the wire.  If you want to do that, you will at the very least need to encrypt the data.  Regardless, the purpose of the example is to show that wherever the service first gets hit is where you need to make *sure* you should continue processing.

Rule of thumb: if you can hit it with a URL, it needs security features.